# I am having problems with Mongob and pushing data with it

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, discord.js

```
const betSave = async (guild, space2, money, user) => {
    const data = {
        space: space2,
        amount: money,
        author: user
    };
    const rulet = await roullete2.find({GuildID: guild.id})
    await roullete2.updateOne({GuildID: guild.id}, {$push: {BetSaver: data}});
    console.log(rulet[0].BetSaver)
}
```

here is my code and when i console log that it just comes like this: []

And tried a lot of things nothing would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the latest version of the document, including the update you made to it after reading it, you would have to read it from the database again:

```js
const betSave = async (guild, space2, money, user) => {
    const data = {
        space: space2,
        amount: money,
        author: user
    };
    let rulet = await roullete2.find({GuildID: guild.id});
    await roullete2.updateOne({GuildID: guild.id}, {$push: {BetSaver: data}});
    rulet = await roullete2.find({GuildID: guild.id});
    console.log(rulet[0].BetSaver);
}
```